# Adding DNS suffix to a Docker Windows network

Tags: windows, docker, networking, docker-compose

Is it possible to add a DNS suffix to a Docker network?

For example, this docker-compose.yml file fragment creates a new nat network connection:

```
networks:
  my-network:
    name: my-network
    driver: nat
```

But I need to set this DNS suffix in the TCP/IPv4 advanced DNS settings:

[image]

The reason for this change is so that IT network firewall policies that rely on this DNS suffix can be applied.